# PHP Echo into textbox based on dropdown value

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo

Im working on a small web application that follows a basic MVC pattern. currently i have data being pulled from a database into an array and im echoing out that value into one textbox (for now)

```
<input type="text" name="txtGasConRes" id="gasConRes" value="<?php echo $typical; ?>" disabled/>
```

The `$typical` value is being retrieved from my Model class into my Controller class and then echoed into the textbox for gas. I have a very similar textbox for Electricity.

My dropdown is as follows:

```
 <select name="heatingType" id="heatingType" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Option</option>
          <option value = "Gas">Gas</option>
          <option value = "Electricity">Electricity</option>
          <option value = "Other">Other</option>          
        </select>
```

I was wondering if theres a way to determine where to echo the `$typical` value. So for example, If the user selected Gas as their heating type, then once the form was submitted it, the value would appear in the Gas textbox. If the user selected Electricity from the dropdown then the value would be echoed out into the Electricity textbox.

Any information will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a job for JavaScript or jQuery if you prefer. You need to setup a handler to detect a change event on the select input. Once the user selects a value, then you can update the text field with text based on what the user has selected.

Not tested but something like this should work.

```
var select = document.getElementById('heatingType');

function updateTextField(selectedValue) {
    switch(selectedValue){
       case 'Gas':
       return 'some text that you want in the text field';
       break;
       // etc.
    }
}

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var selectedValue = this.value,
    textField = document.getElementById('gasConRes');

    textField.value = updateTextField(selectedValue);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Im fairly new to both JavaScript and jQuery. would it be possible for you to point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Just updated the answer to include code. Not tested but should work or be nearly there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I kinda understand that code but from what i can see wouldnt that just display the value solely in the `gasConRes` textbox?

Comment: If you can't work out how to modify what I've written for you to put into another text box then you should hire a developer to do it for you. Stack Overflow is not a 'we write scripts for you for free' service.

Answer (score 0):

Create javascript function and put function in select box onchange event.(following code is working)

```
 <script>

  function heatingType(obj){
    alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value); //if you want to show in alart
    //or put in a variable 
    $x=obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;

  }

</script>

 <select name="heatingType" id="heatingType"  onChange="heatingType(this)" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Option</option>
          <option value = "Gas">Gas</option>
          <option value = "Electricity">Electricity</option>
          <option value = "Other">Other</option>          
        </select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but that doesnt do what im asking for.